# Getting individual pixels of another window with BitBlt

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, bitblt, getpixel

This is what I am currently doing:

- get window DC via `GetWindowDC`
- create a compatible DC with `CreateCompatibleDC`
- call `GetPixel` on my compatible DC

Unfortunately, all of my GetPixel calls are returning `CLR_INVALID`. Here is my code.

```
bool Gameboard::Refresh()
{
  bool  ret = false;
  HDC   context, localContext;

  context = GetWindowDC(m_window);
  if (context != NULL)
  {
    localContext = CreateCompatibleDC(context);
    if (localContext != NULL)
    {
      if (BitBlt(localContext, 0, 0, GameboardInfo::BoardWidth, GameboardInfo::BoardHeight,
        context, GameboardInfo::TopLeft.x, GameboardInfo::TopLeft.y, SRCCOPY))
      {
        ret = true;
        // several calls to GetPixel which all return CLR_INVALID
      }
      DeleteDC(localContext);
    }
    ReleaseDC(m_window, context);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to select a bitmap into your device context.

"A bitmap must be selected within the device context, otherwise, CLR_INVALID is returned on all pixels." - [GetPixel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
bool Gameboard::Refresh()
{
  bool  ret = false;
  HDC   context, localContext;


  HGDIOBJ origHandle;


  context = GetWindowDC(m_window);
  if (context != NULL)
  {
    localContext = CreateCompatibleDC(context);


    origHandle = SelectObject(localcontext,CreateCompatibleBitmap(context, GameboardInfo::BoardWidth, GameboardInfo::BoardHeight));


    if (localContext != NULL)
    {
      if (BitBlt(localContext, 0, 0, GameboardInfo::BoardWidth, GameboardInfo::BoardHeight,
        context, GameboardInfo::TopLeft.x, GameboardInfo::TopLeft.y, SRCCOPY))
      {
        ret = true;
        // several calls to GetPixel which all return CLR_INVALID
      }

      SelectObject(localcontext, origHandle);


      DeleteDC(localContext);
    }
    ReleaseDC(m_window, context);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the x/y values in my GetPixel calls are already offsets not absolute locations.

Comment: You still need to select a bitmap into your compatible DC, otherwise BitBlt has nowhere to copy the pixels to. Also, use GetDIBits -- it's much quicker than using GetPixel.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe What if I only need 64 pixels, out of a 480x480 square? Is GetDIBits still faster?

Comment: Any extended error information? Win 32 APIs usually don't hang without generating some error, at least in the debugger.

Comment: If you're getting more than one pixel CreateComaptilbeBitmap(hDC,nWidth,nHieght). If you want to use GetDIBits instead, you don't use BitBlt. GetDIBits returns a pointer to the bits themselves, so you could actually traverse or examine them yourself, or you could use CreateDIBSection and StretchDIBits to copy only the bits you want to examine.

Comment: Sudden thought: a pointer to the bits could be effectively casted as a `COLORREF*`, right?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688409/getdibits-and-loop-through-pixels-using-x-y for how to use getdibits to get an array of pixels. Yes, I believe you could could cast the point to the buffer to a `COLORREF*` and move to the next pixel with `myCOLORREF += 4;`

Comment: ***Actually, COLORREF is a 0x00bbggrr color order, colors from getdibits will be 0xrrggbb00 byte order, so you shouldn't use colorref unless you want to reverse the byte order***