# Getting the screen pixels as byte array

Tags: c#, winapi, screen-capture, bitblt

I need to change my screen capture code to get a pixel array instead of a Bitmap.

I change the code to this:

```
BitBlt > Image.FromHbitmap(pointer) > LockBits > pixel array
```

But, I'm checking if it's possible to cut some middle man, and have something like this:

```
BitBlt > Marshal.Copy > pixel array
```

Or even:

```
WinApi method that gets the screen region as a pixel array
```

So far, I tried to use this code, without success:

```
public static byte[] CaptureAsArray(Size size, int positionX, int positionY)
{
    var hDesk = GetDesktopWindow();
    var hSrce = GetWindowDC(hDesk);
    var hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hSrce);
    var hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hSrce, (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
    var hOldBmp = SelectObject(hDest, hBmp);

    try
    {
        new System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission(System.Security.Permissions.UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows).Demand();

        var b = BitBlt(hDest, 0, 0, (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, hSrce, positionX, positionY, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy | CopyPixelOperation.CaptureBlt);

        var length = 4 * (int)size.Width * (int)size.Height;
        var bytes = new byte[length];

        Marshal.Copy(hBmp, bytes, 0, length);

        //return b ? Image.FromHbitmap(hBmp) : null;
        return bytes;
    }
    finally
    {
        SelectObject(hDest, hOldBmp);
        DeleteObject(hBmp);
        DeleteDC(hDest);
        ReleaseDC(hDesk, hSrce);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This code gives me an `System.AccessViolationException` while stepping on `Marshal.Copy`.

Is there any more efficient way of getting screen pixels as a byte array while using BitBlt or similar screen capture methods?

---

EDIT:

As found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16115730/1735672) and as suggested by CodyGray, I should use

```
var b = Native.BitBlt(_compatibleDeviceContext, 0, 0, Width, Height, _windowDeviceContext, Left, Top, Native.CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy | Native.CopyPixelOperation.CaptureBlt);

var bi = new Native.BITMAPINFOHEADER();
bi.biSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(bi);
bi.biBitCount = 32; 
bi.biClrUsed = 0;
bi.biClrImportant = 0;
bi.biCompression = 0;
bi.biHeight = Height;
bi.biWidth = Width;
bi.biPlanes = 1;

var data = new byte[4 * Width * Height];

Native.GetDIBits(_windowDeviceContext, _compatibleBitmap, 0, (uint)Height, data, ref bi, Native.DIB_Color_Mode.DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

My `data` array has all the pixels of the screenshot. 
Now, I'm going to test if there's any performance improvements or not.

Comment: You use `hBmp` (essentially `Bitmap.GetHBitmap`) as if it was `BitmapData.Scan0`. These pointers are different. What was wrong with `BitmapData` anyway? If you want to use some managed wrapper for GDI+ that's your best choice. It ends up in the same extern calls you would use anyway.

Comment: Indeed, they are different pointers. I'm just trying to know if reduce the capture lag.

Comment: You wouldn't gain much as `LockBits` is a simple call to `GdipBitmapLockBits` in gdiplus.dll, which fills up a `BitmapData`. You would just do the same. The most performance is lost at `Marshal.Copy`, imho.

Comment: You could study the code of a good screen capture application: https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg I found the solution that I wanted in another website. They basically use `GetDIBits` to get the array. I'm going to test it.

Comment: I'm not sure why my comment got deleted, but your comment was not useful, @Aybe since they use the same code as I do. You didn't read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can't just start accessing the raw bits of a `BITMAP` object through an `HBITMAP` (as returned by `CreateCompatibleBitmap`). `HBITMAP` is just a handle, as the name suggests. It's not a pointer in the classic "C" sense that it points to the beginning of the array. Handles are like indirect pointers.

`GetDIBits` is the appropriate solution to get the raw, device-independent pixel array from a bitmap that you can iterate through. But you'll still need to use the code you have to get the screen bitmap in the first place. Essentially, you want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26238387). Of course, you'll need to translate it into C#, but that shouldn't be difficult, since you already know how to call WinAPI functions.

Note that you do not need to call `GetDesktopWindow` or `GetWindowDC`. Just pass `NULL` as the handle to `GetDC`; it has the same effect of returning a screen DC, which you can then use to create a compatible bitmap. In general, you should almost never call `GetDesktopWindow`.

Comment: Yes, I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16115730/1735672 a few minutes ago and converted to C#. It works ;)