# How to convert HBITMAP to image.Image

Tags: go, winapi, data-conversion

I want to retrieve an image from a specific application and convert it to image.Image for later use.

What I have now is a HBITMAP from windows API call. After trying a lots, I can't manage to convert the created HBITMAP to an image.Image (or at least an []byte).

```
rc := w32.GetClientRect(hwnd)
if rc != nil {
    // create
    HDCScreen := w32.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    hdc := w32.CreateCompatibleDC(HDCScreen)
    hbmp := w32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(HDCScreen, int(rc.Right)-int(rc.Left), int(rc.Bottom)-int(rc.Top))
    w32.SelectObject(hdc, w32.HGDIOBJ(hbmp))

    // Print to memory hdc
    w32.PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, 0x00000002)

    // ------------------------------------------------
    var bmpInfo *w32.BITMAPINFO = &w32.BITMAPINFO{}
    bmpInfo.BmiHeader.BiSize = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(bmpInfo.BmiHeader))

    firstDIBits := w32.GetDIBits(HDCScreen, hbmp, 0, 0, nil, bmpInfo, w32.DIB_RGB_COLORS)
    fmt.Printf("firstDIBits: %v\n", firstDIBits)

    var lpPixels *[]byte
    bmpInfo.BmiHeader.BiBitCount = 32
    bmpInfo.BmiHeader.BiCompression = w32.BI_RGB
    bmpInfo.BmiHeader.BiHeight = int32(math.Abs(float64(bmpInfo.BmiHeader.BiHeight)))
    bmpInfo.BmiHeader.BiCompression = w32.BI_RGB

    secondDIBits := w32.GetDIBits(hdc, hbmp, 0, uint(bmpInfo.BmiHeader.BiHeight), unsafe.Pointer(lpPixels), bmpInfo, w32.DIB_RGB_COLORS)
    fmt.Printf("secondDIBits: %v\n", secondDIBits)
    fmt.Printf("lpPixels: %v\n", lpPixels)

    // ------------------------------------------------

    // copy to clipBoard
    w32.OpenClipboard(0)
    w32.EmptyClipboard()
    w32.SetClipboardData(w32.CF_BITMAP, w32.HANDLE(hbmp))
    w32.CloseClipboard()

    // release
    w32.DeleteDC(hdc)
    w32.DeleteObject(w32.HGDIOBJ(hbmp))
    w32.ReleaseDC(0, HDCScreen)
}
```

Both of GetDIBits() call return 1 but lpPixels is always nil.

Answer (score 0):

The Bitmap class inherits from the Image class.In my opinion, you couldn't need the conversion.

According to the Doc:[GetDIBits function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdibits)

> [out] lpvBits
>
> A pointer to a buffer to receive the bitmap data. If this parameter is
> NULL, the function passes the dimensions and format of the bitmap to
> the BITMAPINFO structure pointed to by the lpbi parameter.

I don't know much about Go language, but the lpvBits parameter of GetDIBits seem incorrect. I suggest you could refer to the threads:

[Using GetDIBits to load a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313903/using-getdibits-to-load-a-bitmap)

[How should I use the GetDIBits function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291774/how-should-i-use-the-getdibits-function)

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it. Posting the code in case it can help someone else. :)

```
rect := image.Rect(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
img := image.NewRGBA(rect)
rc := w32.GetClientRect(hwnd)
    if rc != nil {
        width := int(rc.Right) - int(rc.Left)
        height := int(rc.Bottom) - int(rc.Top)
        hwndwin := win.HWND(hwnd)
        hdc := win.GetDC(hwndwin)
        if hdc == 0 {
            panic("GetDC failed")
        }
        defer win.ReleaseDC(hwndwin, hdc)

        memory_device := win.CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)
        if memory_device == 0 {
            panic("CreateCompatibleDC failed")
        }
        defer win.DeleteDC(memory_device)

        bitmap := win.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, int32(width), int32(height))
        if bitmap == 0 {
            panic("CreateCompatibleBitmap failed")
        }
        defer win.DeleteObject(win.HGDIOBJ(bitmap))

        var header win.BITMAPINFOHEADER
        header.BiSize = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(header))
        header.BiPlanes = 1
        header.BiBitCount = 32
        header.BiWidth = int32(width)
        header.BiHeight = int32(-height)
        header.BiCompression = win.BI_RGB
        header.BiSizeImage = 0

        // GetDIBits balks at using Go memory on some systems. The MSDN example uses GlobalAlloc
        // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/gdi/capturing-an-image
        bitmapDataSize := uintptr(((int64(width)*int64(header.BiBitCount) + 31) / 32) * 4 * int64(height))
        hmem := win.GlobalAlloc(win.GMEM_MOVEABLE, bitmapDataSize)
        defer win.GlobalFree(hmem)
        memptr := win.GlobalLock(hmem)
        defer win.GlobalUnlock(hmem)

        old := win.SelectObject(memory_device, win.HGDIOBJ(bitmap))
        if old == 0 {
            panic("SelectObject failed")
        }
        defer win.SelectObject(memory_device, old)

        if !win.BitBlt(memory_device, 0, 0, int32(width), int32(height), hdc, int32(0), int32(0), win.SRCCOPY) {
            panic("BitBlt failed")
        }

        if win.GetDIBits(hdc, bitmap, 0, uint32(height), (*uint8)(memptr), (*win.BITMAPINFO)(unsafe.Pointer(&header)), win.DIB_RGB_COLORS) == 0 {
            panic("GetDIBits failed")
        }

        i := 0
        src := uintptr(memptr)
        for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
            for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
                v0 := *(*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(src))
                v1 := *(*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(src + 1))
                v2 := *(*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(src + 2))

                // BGRA => RGBA, and set A to 255
                img.Pix[i], img.Pix[i+1], img.Pix[i+2], img.Pix[i+3] = v2, v1, v0, 255

                i += 4
                src += 4
            }
        }
```