# GetDIBits returns array with all values 0

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, getdibits

I need to find some image on screen. I decided to make a simple comparing loop.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3688682/15220214) that seems to be helpfull and wrote the next code:

```
void Capt()
{
  HDC hdcSource = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow()); // the source device context
  HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSource);
  HBITMAP hSource = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSource, xw, yw); // the bitmap selected into the device context

  SelectObject(hdc, hSource);

  BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo = { 0 };
  MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader);

  // Get the BITMAPINFO structure from the bitmap
  if (0 == GetDIBits(hdc, hSource, 0, 0, NULL, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
  {
    mb("error1");
    IA(GetLastError());
  }

  // create the pixel buffer
  BYTE* lpPixels = new BYTE[MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];

  // We'll change the received BITMAPINFOHEADER to request the data in a
  // 32 bit RGB format (and not upside-down) so that we can iterate over
  // the pixels easily. 

  // requesting a 32 bit image means that no stride/padding will be necessary,
  // although it always contains an (possibly unused) alpha channel
  MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
  MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;  // no compression -> easier to use
  // correct the bottom-up ordering of lines (abs is in cstdblib and stdlib.h)
  MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = abs(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight);

  // Call GetDIBits a second time, this time to (format and) store the actual
  // bitmap data (the "pixels") in the buffer lpPixels
  if (0 == GetDIBits(hdc, hSource, 0, MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight,
    lpPixels, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
  {
    mb("error2");
    IA(GetLastError());
  }

  DeleteObject(hSource);
  ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcSource);


  for (int i = 0, j=0; i < MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage&&j<100; i++)
  {
    if (lpPixels[i] != 0)
    {
      char buf[1024] = {};
      _itoa_s(lpPixels[i], buf, 10);
  
      //output
    }
  }
}
```

Two problems:

1. My screen resolution is 1280x800=1 024 000 px, `MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage` is equal to 4 096 000. Is it rgb**a** or what?
2. The main issue: although, there is no errors, and the value I mentioned in previous problem is not zero, but in the loop at the bottom of code, all values of `lpPixels` are zero, I do not get any output. Why?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question ... but where do you copy the screen's pixel values into your hdc? Shouldn't there be a `BitBlt` or some such between `hdcSource` (the screen) and `hdc` (your local DC/bitmap)?

Comment: You're pulling data from a brand-new bitmap.  Try using BitBlt to copy some data from `hdcSource` to `hdc`.

Comment: As well as above comments, you don't need the intermediate compatible bitmap. You can use `CreateDIBSection` to create a DIB and blit directly from the screen to that.

Comment: @AdrianMole @BenVoight I try `BitBlt` for a minute

Comment: @BenVoigt added `BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, xw, yw, hdcSource, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);` and nothing is changed. `xw` and `yw` are window width and height.

Comment: @JonathanPotter can You please specify what should I pass to `CreateDIBSection`, because in my case it all should work the fastest as possible. Should I call it twice as `GetDIBits`?

Comment: @BenVoigt, oh, my fault, `BitBlt` in fact worked. This seems to solve my problem

Comment: @BenVoigt but now I am confused of how to work with array. I am totally confused. I think the reason of pixel array size is getting 4 times bigger is related to the bit count — 32, i.e. 4 byte. But... so what?). First element of the pixel array is red value of first pixel; second value is green value of first pixel; third is red; what is fourth then?

Comment: @Thawbkisavv: Well, it depends on the other fields in the BITMAPINFOHEADER.  Specifically you want to look at the one "number of color planes".  If it is 4, then there is a fourth color plane (alpha).  If it is 3, then the fourth byte is just meaningless padding.  Either way you probably want to just cast to (RGBQUAD*)lpPixels` and away you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For screen data without transparency, you can simply set the fourth byte (Alpha) to 255, which means opaque.

The color format of the bitmap data obtained by `GetDIBits` is written in BGR (`lpPixels` parameter). If we want to assign data to a byte array using RGB format, we need to perform some conversion.

e.p.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myWidth * myHeight; i++)
    {
        size_t tempIndex = (i * 4);

        // The colors are in BGR-format (windows format)
        // Hence, the order is reversed
        rgbPixels[tempIndex] = bgrPixels[tempIndex + 2]; // r
        rgbPixels[tempIndex + 1] = bgrPixels[tempIndex + 1]; // g
        rgbPixels[tempIndex + 2] = bgrPixels[tempIndex]; // b
        rgbPixels[tempIndex + 3] = 255; // a (always 255)
    }
```

Updated:

```
HDC hdc, hdcTemp;
RECT rect;
BYTE* bitPointer;
int x, y;
int red, green, blue, alpha;

hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
GetWindowRect(hWND_Desktop, &rect);
int MAX_WIDTH = rect.right;
int MAX_HEIGHT = rect.bottom;

hdcTemp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
BITMAPINFO bitmap;
bitmap.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bitmap.bmiHeader);
bitmap.bmiHeader.biWidth = MAX_WIDTH;
bitmap.bmiHeader.biHeight = MAX_HEIGHT;
bitmap.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bitmap.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bitmap.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bitmap.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = MAX_WIDTH * 4 * MAX_HEIGHT;
bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
bitmap.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
HBITMAP hBitmap2 = CreateDIBSection(hdcTemp, &bitmap, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)(&bitPointer), NULL, NULL);
SelectObject(hdcTemp, hBitmap2);
BitBlt(hdcTemp, 0, 0, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

for (int i=0; i<(MAX_WIDTH * 4 * MAX_HEIGHT); i+=4)
{
    red = (int)bitPointer[i];
    green = (int)bitPointer[i+1];
    blue = (int)bitPointer[i+2];
    alpha = (int)bitPointer[i+3];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can You please also specify the solution for my second question, with `BitBlt`, for example?

Comment: @Thawbkisavv I updated my answer . I made a sample using `CreateDIBSection` and `BitBlt`.